# Updating a widget layout from an XML file at run time

Tags: android, widget

I have written an android widget that updates every hour, I know is it possible to change some views of the widget at runtime, using a setting menu in main activity, for example, change the text showing on the widget, but is it possible to update entire XML file of the widget at runtime? (by loading it from an XML file at run time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For efficiency, the XML files in the bundle are not just XML files.  Part of building the app is compiling these to a more efficient format for the app.  Due to that, you can't load a layout xml file at runtime.  You'd need to parse it yourself and create a view hierarchy off it-  basically you'd need to write your own version of LayoutInflater.  And if you wanted to change an already inflated version of the View it would need to be passed that view and update everything one call at a time.